# Laravel - Problems with updating to Laravel 5.4. Way module share() error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is regarding Laravel and I am still pretty new to the framework. I recently updated my Laravel to 5.4. And I am running into the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]              
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()
```

Some investigation landed me on one of my vendor module 'Way' is still call share(), which is no longer supported. I did realize that singleton() is the preferred way, but should I even touch the vendor files? Should composer update the vendor Modules as well (especially Way since it is one of the core module)?

Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: If the other library does not support laravel 5.4 yet (which seems to be the case) consider contributing to the library by making changes and making a pull request.

Comment: @apokryfos Actually it seems like the author has updated the code on GitHub, but I can't pull it for some reason.

I don't think I can make manual changes on vendor can I?

Comment: Make sure (1) the author has released the relevant change as part of a new version (2) your `composer.json` file is requiring that new version (3) you `composer update` . If it hasn't been packaged as a new version yet then you won't be able to get it

Comment: Thanks! The update was not included in Laravel update but i was able to change the composer to fix this.

    "way/generators": "dev-master"

Answer (score 0):

laravel 5.4 `share` has been removed. You will have to use the `singleton` instead.

See this 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1a1969b6e6f793c3b2a479362641487ee9cbf736

Comment: I actually did state that I know this in my question, but thanks for your input either way.

Answer (score 0):

This library does not have support for Laravel 5.4 .

Author referred other library : `laracasts/generators`. Both the packages are managed by same author.

Check below link : https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#laravel-5

Comment: Thanks. I did found a way to fix this. We are looking at the same library with the same author here.

Comment: I suggest you to use new library which I mentioned. As author himself suggest to use `laracast/generators`. Apart from that `laracast/generators` has many more features than `way/generators`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it for now by adjusting the way generator line in composer.json to:

```
"way/generators": "dev-master"
```

The library was updated but it is just not included in the composer update.

Just want to post the answer here in case anyone is running into similar issue.